# Auto Increment Id MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, auto-increment, crud

I am new to MVC and i'm trying to create an auto incrementing id upon using CRUD create.
I've created my model with id :

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
```

and my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.OpticianId = new SelectList(db.Opticans, "OpticianId", "UserId");
        ViewBag.PatientId = new SelectList(db.Patients, "PatientId", "HCN");
        ViewBag.PracticeId = new SelectList(db.Practices, "PracticeId", "PracticeName");
        ViewBag.AppointmentTime = new SelectList(db.Times, "AppointmentTime", "AppointmentTime");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BookingId,Date,PracticeId,AppointmentTime,OpticianId,PatientId")] Booking booking)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Bookings.Add(booking);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

        ViewBag.OpticianId = new SelectList(db.Opticans, "OpticianId", "UserId", booking.OpticianId);
        ViewBag.PatientId = new SelectList(db.Patients, "PatientId", "HCN", booking.PatientId);
        ViewBag.PracticeId = new SelectList(db.Practices, "PracticeId", "PracticeName", booking.PracticeId);
        ViewBag.AppointmentTime = new SelectList(db.Times, "AppointmentTime", "AppointmentTime", booking.AppointmentTime);
        return View(booking);
    }
```

I have removed the Booking id from the view but when I try to add a new booking I am getting the following exception:

> 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException'
>
> StackTrace    "   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at
>   CSCOpticians.Controllers.BookingsController.Create(Booking booking) in
>   c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\CSCOpticians\CSCOpticians\Controllers\BookingsController.cs:line
>   89\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )\r\n
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()\r\n
>   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Object tag)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()"    string

Comment: What is the message of the DbUpdateException?

Comment: @MartinNoreke I've added the stacktrace above

Comment: The stack doesn't help, we need the message; it should tell you directly what the error is.

Comment: @BrianMains The exception is at the db.SaveChanges(); - "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details" How do I view the inner exception?

Comment: What happens when you replace `db.Bookings.Add(booking);` with (excuse formatting) `db.Bookings.Add(new Booking{Date = booking.Date, PracticeId = booking.PracticeId, AppointmentTime = booking.AppointmentTime, OpticianId = booking.OpticianId, PatientId = booking.PatientId});`

Answer (score 0):

You have removed **BookingID** in the view but removed also the BookingID in **Bind**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Date,PracticeId,AppointmentTime,OpticianId,PatientId")] Booking booking)
```

Comment: I tried that but it is stlll throwing the same exception